# arranging views in framelayout

Tags: android, xml

[image: What I want]

The best I could explain this is by the image above. I have 4 views(1,2,3,4) which are linear and relative layouts and I have 5 which is a linear layout inside of 1, but 5 has to overlap 2.

If I contain 1,2,3,4 inside a linear layout I can arrange them but 5 wouldn't then be able to overlap 2 it would be cut off by it, I tried `view5.bringToFront(); view5.invalidate();` but it didn't work.

So I guess 1,2,3,4 must be contained within a framelayout, but how then would I be able to align them vertically the way a linearlayout would do(1 then 2 then 3 then 4 above each other like the image provided)

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple hierarchy in this case. The view that is written first will be drawn first. SO if you want your 5th view to come on top of your linear layout make your xml like this

```
<FrameLayout
  .........
  .........

  <LinearLayout
       ............
       ............
       />

   <View
        ......5th view...
        .................
        />


</FrameLayout>
```